# Count (field) and Count(distinct field) both outputting wrong counts in SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have 2 tables i am joining, and have created a unique field, a concatenation of 2 string fields. When trying to get a count of that unique field using count(unique_field), I get an incorrect count. My unique_field does include nulls in some of the results, which are being counted correctly. When using count(distinct unique_field) I get 1's and 0's, which is also incorrect. What is a way I can figure this count out??

```
SELECT DISTINCT        
    CONCAT(product_id,'_', channel_id ) as unique_id,
    count(DISTINCT unique_id) as unique_id_count,
    field c,
    field d
From tablea full outer join tableb
ON tablea.product_id=tableb.product_id
group by 3,4
```

Example output: column A is  unique_Id, Column B is actual count of unique_Id, and column c is the results of unique_id_count

[image]

Comment: running your SQL gives a `ambiguous column name 'PRODUCT_ID'` error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding you want to count how many occurrences exist for an individual unique_id.

Therefore, I would suggest to group by unique_id and not by field c and field d.

```
SELECT DISTINCT        
    CONCAT(product_id,'_', channel_id ) as unique_id,
    count(DISTINCT unique_id) as unique_id_count
From tablea full outer join tableb
ON tablea.product_id=tableb.product_id
group by CONCAT(product_id,'_', channel_id )
```

Comment: Unfortunately, i get an error "SQL compilation error: error line 5 at position 16 'field c' in select clause is neither an aggregate nor in the group by clause". I am forced to have the other fields in the group by clause for it to run.

Answer (score 0):

so if we "try" make your SQL valid:

```
with tablea(product_id) as (
    select * from values
    ('a'),
    ('b'),
    ('c'),
    ('d'),
    ('e')
), tableb(product_id, channel_id) as (
    select * from values
    ('a', '1'),
    ('a', '2'),
    ('b', '3')
)
SELECT        
    CONCAT(NVL(a.product_id,b.product_id),'_', b.channel_id ) as unique_id
    ,count(DISTINCT unique_id) as unique_id_count
    --field c,
    --field d
From tablea as a
full outer join tableb as b
    ON a.product_id = b.product_id
group by 1
```

gives:

| UNIQUE_ID | UNIQUE_ID_COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| a_1 | 1 |
| a_2 | 1 |
| b_3 | 1 |
| null | 0 |

Which makes sense as in this data there is only "one" thing per grouping. Now I get you had some fields c & d

so maybe like:

```
with tablea(product_id, field) as (
    select * from values
    ('a', 1),
    ('b', 1),
    ('c', 2),
    ('d', 2),
    ('e', 2)
), tableb(product_id, channel_id, field) as (
    select * from values
    ('a', '1', 10),
    ('a', '2', 10),
    ('a', '2', 10),
    ('b', '3', 10)
)
SELECT        
    CONCAT(NVL(a.product_id,b.product_id),'_', b.channel_id ) as unique_id
    ,count(DISTINCT unique_id) as unique_id_count
    ,a.field as c
    ,b.field as d
From tablea as a
full outer join tableb as b
    ON a.product_id = b.product_id
group by c, d
```

but this is not valid as `unique_id` is confusing the SQL, so we can inline that:

```
SELECT        
    count(DISTINCT CONCAT(NVL(a.product_id,b.product_id),'_', b.channel_id )) as unique_id_count
    ,a.field as c
    ,b.field as d
From tablea as a
full outer join tableb as b
    ON a.product_id = b.product_id
group by c, d
```

gives:

| UNIQUE_ID_COUNT | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 10 |
| 0 | 2 | null |

But what you are trying to do is somewhat confusing.

Comment: Thank you for helping try to figure it out. Yes I did forget to add the prefix to the product_id in the unique_id aggregate. My goal is to remove the duplicate rows based in the output based on only on that unique ID field. I was going to add a statement in the where clause to filter out the dups counts. Is there a different approach I can do, like not use the count, and a have a way to remove out the duplicate rows in the output?